# Bottom align image within auto height parent

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm having two divs with the same height but different content. This content is dynamic made with a CMS. However I want to make the image and button to always be at the bottom of the div. How can I accomplish this? because I only get it to work if I use a fixed height, I never works with height: auto;

here is my HTML/CSS snippet

```css
.box:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
 margin-right: 10%;
}

.box {
 width: 45%;
 height: auto;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 box-shadow: 0 15px 14px -3px #d1daeb;
}

.box a {
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 600;
 letter-spacing: -0.2px;
 color: #602b96;
 padding: 15px 50px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.box a:hover {
 color: #ffffff;
}

.box div {
 padding: 35px 40px 0px 40px;
}

.box img {
 padding-top: 35px;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>
    <h2>Tittle of my div</h2>
    <hr>
    <span class="clearfix"></span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <a class="buttonArticle" href="#">VIEW</a>
  </div>
  <img src="http://gbchope.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/events-placeholder.jpg" alt="" class="">
</div>


<div class="box">
  <div>
    <h2>Tittle of my div</h2>
    <hr>
    <span class="clearfix"></span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <a class="buttonArticle" href="#">VIEW</a>
  </div>
  <img src="http://gbchope.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/events-placeholder.jpg" alt="" class="">
</div>
```

This is how it looks now:

[image]

How sould i do this?

Comment: Just place the image and 'view article' button below the CMS generated content in the HTML code.

Comment: They are all inside the .box class, since there is some shadow underneath it. The content is generated with laravel between each html tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with `flex` and change some `html`

```css
.box-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}
.box:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
 margin-right: 10%;
}

.box {
   width: 45%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 14px -3px #d1daeb;
    align-items: start;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.box a {
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 600;
 letter-spacing: -0.2px;
 color: #602b96;
 padding: 15px 50px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.box a:hover {
 color: #ffffff;
}

.box div {
 padding: 35px 40px 0px 40px;
}

.box img {
 padding-top: 35px;
 width: 100%;
}
.mt-auto {
  margin-top: auto;
}
.p-0 {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-wrapper">
<div class="box">
  <div>
    <h2>Tittle of my div</h2>
    <hr>
    <span class="clearfix"></span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    
  </div>
  <div class="mt-auto p-0">
  <a class="buttonArticle" href="#">VIEW</a>
  <img src="http://gbchope.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/events-placeholder.jpg" alt="" class="">
  </div>
</div>


<div class="box">
  <div>
    <h2>Tittle of my div</h2>
    <hr>
    <span class="clearfix"></span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    
  </div>
  <div class="mt-auto">
  <a class="buttonArticle" href="#">VIEW</a>
  <img src="http://gbchope.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/events-placeholder.jpg" alt="" class="">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: See my answer, Buttons and Images are at the bottom @Ramon

Comment: Thanks, this is the way i want it. However, is there a way to make the img the full width of the .box element? the width 100% does not work annymore

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by flex. These are the styles that I added

```
body {
    margin:0;
    display: flex;
}
.box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.box img {
    margin-top: auto;
    padding-top: 35px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

---

```css
body {
margin:0;
display: flex;
}

.box:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
 margin-right: 10%;
}

.box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
 width: 45%;
 height: auto;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 box-shadow: 0 15px 14px -3px #d1daeb;
}

.box a {
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 600;
 letter-spacing: -0.2px;
 color: #602b96;
 padding: 15px 50px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.box a:hover {
 color: #ffffff;
}

.box div {
 padding: 35px 40px 0px 40px;
}

.box img {
    margin-top: auto;
 padding-top: 35px;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>
    <h2>Tittle of my div</h2>
    <hr>
    <span class="clearfix"></span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <a class="buttonArticle" href="#">VIEW</a>
  </div>
  <img src="http://gbchope.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/events-placeholder.jpg" alt="" class="">
</div>


<div class="box">
  <div>
    <h2>Tittle of my div</h2>
    <hr>
    <span class="clearfix"></span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <a class="buttonArticle" href="#">VIEW</a>
  </div>
  <img src="http://gbchope.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/events-placeholder.jpg" alt="" class="">
</div>
```

Comment: This did it, i kept trying to do it with position relative and absolute.. Thanks allot

Comment: buttons are not at the bottom @Ramon